# How can I make an area of a website password protected through Apache?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have been working on this for a while, and I am trying to use `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.  Here is what I have done:

Performed with Apache using Raspberry Pi 3B+ with DietPi installed.

- I created a new `.htpasswd` file and proceeded to enter password that I wanted.
- Next, I redirected to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` where I edited `000-default.conf` and changed the line of code:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *80>
  ServerName www.example.com
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /var/www/

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      <Directory "/var/www/etc/"
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "Restricted Content"
          AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
          Require valid-user
      </Directory>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
      RewriteRule ^https://%{SERVER_NAME%{REQUEST_URI} [END,Ne,R=permanent]
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Everything here is the same, except replace "example" with my domain.

This did not affect my site, so I redirected to `/etc/apache2/` where I edited `apache2.conf` and added the line of code:

```
<Directory /var/www/etc/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Once again, everything here is the same. etc is the file that I want to password-protect. This made the page that I wanted to protect completely inaccessible, and when I changed `AllowOverride` and `Require all` it just made the page completely open. How can I make it so that a password is prompted when you try to access the directory?

Comment: There are many guides and tutorials for this. One thing you did not mention anywhere is if you restarted Apache.  Any time you change the config file, you need to restart before it will take effect.  Another minor thing, your terminology is confusing, "redirect" means something very specific when talking about web servers, but AFAICT you are just talking about editing config files.  `This made the page that I wanted to protect completely inaccessible` - what does that mean? Be specific - error messages?  HTTP response codes? Pls see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, until you get things working, keep it simple.  Get rid of your redirects, `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}`, anything you can to get the simplest version working.  Once you have it working, you can iteratively add extra bells and whistles.

Comment: I have checked a lot of tutorials and followed them step for step. I did restart Apache. By "redirect," I meant changed directories. The error message was: Forbidden You do not have access to access this resource.